# Interface for Open Cascade in Delphi

Tags: delphi, activex, vcl, opencascade

I am trying to find a way to use [Open Cascade](http://www.opencascade.org)(www.opencascade.org) - 3D Modeling Technology in one of our software which is written in Delphi.

I did manage top find an ActiveX which supports Open Cascade, but on trying it I did not like the visual quality of rendered images. The ActiveX lib can be found [here](http://www.ewcad.com) (www.ewcad.com).

I am not able to locate any VCL for this nor can I find any import declarations for this on internet.

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think that the visual output quality would be higher if you had a native VCL wrapper?  The underlying library is C++, not C, so import libraries are not going to be enough.  A "C++ class to VCL wrapper" interface for such a large project would be years of work.

Have you looked at GLScene?  http://glscene.sourceforge.net/wikka/HomePage

W

Comment: I have looked at GLScene but it seems to be dead without any active Development. The last message was GLScene is gearing up for new release in March 2007 after that nothing is released except a new message stating that GLScene is alive. Another thing, probably GLScene does not support 3D parametric modeling.

As for visual output I mean that what is rendered on screen by the ActiveX is not that sharp and clear as compared to what is rendered by native sample application. Another thing is that Delphi is not able to import the ActiveX properly so I had to try in VB6.

Answer (score 0):

I am using OCC from Delphi through a DLL exporting ANSI C functions. It was not required to export all of the more then 12000 Objects, just a set of wrapper functions to initialize, add geometry, modify it and store it to Disk.

I started with one of sample Applications provided with the OCC package and converted it to my personal DLL, wich is loaded at runtime.

It took me about 2 weeks for the first working sample.